# Regular Expression to help with Rewriting a URL

Tags: c#, regex

I have strings like this:

```
http://localhost:2055/web-site-2009/paginas/noticias/**IGP-M recua 0,36% em agosto, aponta FGV**-46.aspx
```

I'd like to remove all characters that could cause trouble on a URL (like ?, |, &, etc.) and the hyphen(-) on the bold part of the string. It's important that I keep the hyphen next to the 46.aspx.

What is the regex for that?

Comment: the hyphen (-) is not a troubling character in a URL. Stackoverflow and most blog and news site use them.

Comment: I know, that's why I included as an extra character. The problem is that my URLRewriting specification uses the hyphen as a separator, so if a hyphen would show up before that one, it would mislead the URLRewriter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another approach would just be to [URL Encode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx) the string. If you need to use a RegEx for some other reason, I think this would get the characters you're asking about:

```
Regex.Replace(stringToCleanUp, "[^a-zA-Z0-9/;\-%:]", string.Empty);
```

Regex explanation:

- Don't match this list of characters - [] means list, ^ means negation
- List of characters: a-z (all characters between a and z lower case)
- List of characters: A-Z (all characters between a and z upper case)
- All numbers: 0-9 (all numbers)
- After that, I've included a list of characters to allow:
  / ; - (have to escape it with \ since - is a reserved character) % :

You can add or remove from that final list - anything in this list will be ALLOWED in your final URL since it will not be replaced.

I recommend using an interactive RegEx tool if you need to tweak this, like [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).

Comment: Very nice tool you've pointed there. But the problem is, I don't understand Regex enough to tweak it the way I want it. Thank you